# JitPack doesn't create an artifact for a GitHub release

Tags: java, git, gradle, jar, jitpack

The [JitPack build log](https://jitpack.io/com/github/THUFIR/hello_api/1/build.log) for release [1](https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_api/releases/tag/1) doesn't load.  Yet, the [JitPack build log](https://jitpack.io/com/github/THUFIR/hello_api/latest/build.log) for [latest](https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_api/releases/tag/latest), which isn't as new as [1](https://jitpack.io/com/github/THUFIR/hello_api/1/build.log), does load.

Why is there no JitPack log for release [1](https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_api/releases/tag/1)?

JitPack [docs](https://jitpack.io/docs/) say it should work fine:

> That’s it! The first time you request a project JitPack checks out the
>   code, builds it and sends the Jar files back to you.